# Make content visible only after using jquery to copy html content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have something like this:

```js
$(".mini-circle").hover(function() {
  $("#circle").html($(this).html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mini-circle" style="background-color:#A9A9A9">circle
  <ul visibility: hidden>
    <li><b>Indecision:</b> Gray prefers to sit in the middle, not making a decision either way, sitting on the fence.</li>
    <li><b>Detached:</b> being non-emotional, gray can appear indifferent, uncaring, cold and aloof.</li>
    <li><b>Unemotional:</b> gray can appear neutral, disinterested, objective or impartial.</li>
  </ul>
</button>

<div class="row">
  <div id="circle" style="background-color:red" align="center">
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the `<ul>` is not visible. I use:

to copy that `<ul>` html section into the lower div. However nothing is visible because it is copied as it is.

```
$($(this).attr('visibility', 'visible')).html()
```

but it is no use. I also tried many other things but the branching is confusing. Do you have any idea how I can tackle this?

Comment: Did you mean `style="visibility: hidden"` in your `ul` tag or this is something I dont know about? o.O

Comment: `<ul visibility: hidden>` isn't valid style approach or valid html

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out, but the problem is still not

Comment: @Sarahcartenz, you want on button click the UL to become visible?

Comment: No. I want to copy ul into div with with id=circle. Then make it visible. For now it is copied but it remains invisible.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz, why don't you just show the UL? This way you have the UL shown and the div with the same content?

Comment: @SimplyMe  The thing is that I have small circles and when i hover over these circles, a big circle appears with that ul. But i only want that text to appear on the big circle, not the small circles. thank you your first answer gave me an idea!

Comment: @Sarahcartenz, I am happy that I could help you! Now I see what you needed. Should have stated this inside the original question as well.
Regarding CSS, I would recommend using the **style** tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working, if this is what you expect (this is what I understand). You need the `<ul>` to become visible on button hover.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".mini-circle").hover(function() {
    $("#circle").html($(this).html());
          $("ul").css("visibility","visible");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <input type="button" class="mini-circle" style="background-color:#A9A9A9" value="circle">
  <ul style="visibility:hidden">
    <li><b>Indecision:</b> Gray prefers to sit in the middle, not making a decision either way, sitting on the fence.</li>
    <li><b>Detached:</b> being non-emotional, gray can appear indifferent, uncaring, cold and aloof.</li>
    <li><b>Unemotional:</b> gray can appear neutral, disinterested, objective or impartial.</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="circle" style="background-color:red" align="center">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: a missing `;` is irrelevant. They are not required in javascript and only impact would be if code was minified

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed. I apologise, forgot that aspect. I will delete my comment unless I can form a useful one.

Comment: The problem persists sadly. I think that it does copy the text but its still invisible.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz, for the style part, you can add the id to the `<ul>` element and style it inline or using the `<style></style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SimplyMe , I got an idea:

```
$(".mini-circle").hover(function()
{
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = $(text).attr('style',"visibility: visible");
    $("#circle").html(text);
});
```

This seems to do the job!